# For loop adding object that is being read as undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem is that length is being read as a property in my for loop. I have four choices in my array but length is coming thru as the 5th and is being read as undefined. Any idea why length is being added?

```
if($scope.ansType==='CHECKBOX') {
  for(var i = 0; $scope.items.length > 0; i++) {
    console.log($scope.items[i]);
    if ($scope.items[i].exclusive === true) {
      $timeout(function () {
        $('input').addClass('none-of-the-above');
        $('.none-of-the-above').on('click', function () {
          $(this).attr('checked');
          $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        });
      },100);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post $scope.items? Or at least something formatted in the same way.

Comment: for(i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++){...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never removing items from the array, that's why your are getting an index out of bounds.
Try this instead
    `for(i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++){...}`

Comment: Just gave it a shot. It's not working entirely. It's adding the none-of-the-above class to every item in my array. I only want to add it to the array that has $scope.items[i].exclusive true. I'm tweaking now. I should get it soon and thanks for your help!